# Hiding and Unhiding List of Elements JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am finishing up JavaScript file that hides/unhides elements from a webpage. The way it should work is when you pick a character from the drop-down box, it filters a play's script and shows ONLY that character's dialogue without the extra whitespace that is created when using `elem.style.opacity = 0.0;`.

The way I went about this is changing the opacity of all lines that are not the selected character's dialogue. Instead, I would need to remove these lines. My limitations are that I cannot use .remove(), JQuery, and I am unable to edit the HTML file in any way.

That is currently my main issue. But also the default option of "Show All Character Lines" doesn't work after you've filtered the results once for some character. If someone can point me in the right direction on how to reset the filtered results or unhide all lines when clicking that option, I would appreciate that. I'm sure I can figure this out on my own, my main concern is filtering character lines.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>

<title>The Tempest, Act V, Scene 1</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link href="plays.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="scene.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="linklist">
   <img src="plays_out.jpg"  alt="The Plays" />
   <img src="son_out.jpg"  alt="The Sonnets" />
   <img src="bio_out.jpg" alt="Biography" />
   <img src="globe_out.jpg" alt="The Globe" />
   <img src="strat_out.jpg" alt="Stratford" />
</div>
<div id="title"><img src="tempest.jpg" alt="The Tempest" /></div>
<div id="actList"><table><tr>
   <td>ACT I</td><td>ACT II</td><td>ACT III</td>
   <td>ACT IV</td><td>ACT V</td>
</tr></table></div>

<div id="characterList"></div>


<div id="sceneIntro">
<h2>Lines from Act V, Scene 1</h2>
</div>

<div id="scene">
<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div><i>Enter PROSPERO in his magic robes, and ARIEL</i></div></blockquote>
<blockquote><div>Now does my project gather to a head:<br />
My charms crack not; my spirits obey; and time<br />
Goes upright with his carriage. How's the day?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote><div>On the sixth hour; at which time, my lord,<br />
You said our work should cease.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>I did say so,<br />
When first I raised the tempest. Say, my spirit,<br/>
How fares the king and's followers?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote><div>Confined together<br />
In the same fashion as you gave in charge,<br />
Just as you left them; all prisoners, sir,<br />
In the line-grove which weather-fends your cell;<br />
They cannot budge till your release. The king,<br />
His brother and yours, abide all three distracted<br />
And the remainder mourning over them,<br />
Brimful of sorrow and dismay; but chiefly<br />
Him that you term'd, sir, 'The good old lord Gonzalo;<br />
His tears run down his beard, like winter's drops<br />
From eaves of reeds. Your charm so strongly works 'em<br />
That if you now beheld them, your affections<br />
Would become tender.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Dost thou think so, spirit?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote><div>Mine would, sir, were I human.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>And mine shall.<br />
Hast thou, which art but air, a touch, a feeling<br />
Of their afflictions, and shall not myself,<br />
One of their kind, that relish all as sharply,<br />
Passion as they, be kindlier moved than thou art?<br />
Though with their high wrongs I am struck to the quick,<br />
Yet with my nobler reason 'gaitist my fury<br />
Do I take part: the rarer action is<br />
In virtue than in vengeance: they being penitent,<br />
The sole drift of my purpose doth extend<br />
Not a frown further. Go release them, Ariel:<br />
My charms I'll break, their senses I'll restore,<br />
And they shall be themselves.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote><div>I'll fetch them, sir.</div></blockquote>

<blockquote><div><i>Exit</i></div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Ye elves of hills, brooks, standing lakes and groves,<br />
And ye that on the sands with printless foot<br />
Do chase the ebbing Neptune and do fly him<br />
When he comes back; you demi-puppets that<br />
By moonshine do the green sour ringlets make,<br />
Whereof the ewe not bites, and you whose pastime<br />
Is to make midnight mushrooms, that rejoice<br />
To hear the solemn curfew; by whose aid,<br />
Weak masters though ye be, I have bedimm'd<br />
The noontide sun, call'd forth the mutinous winds,<br />
And 'twixt the green sea and the azured vault<br />
Set roaring war: to the dread rattling thunder<br />
Have I given fire and rifted Jove's stout oak<br />
With his own bolt; the strong-based promontory<br />
Have I made shake and by the spurs pluck'd up<br />
The pine and cedar: graves at my command<br />
Have waked their sleepers, oped, and let 'em forth<br />
By my so potent art. But this rough magic<br />
I here abjure, and, when I have required<br />
Some heavenly music, which even now I do,<br />
To work mine end upon their senses that<br />
This airy charm is for, I'll break my staff,<br />
Bury it certain fathoms in the earth,<br />
And deeper than did ever plummet sound<br />
I'll drown my book.
</div></blockquote>

<blockquote><div><i>Solemn music</i></div></blockquote>

<blockquote><div><i>Re-enter ARIEL before: then ALONSO, with a frantic gesture, attended by GONZALO; SEBASTIAN and ANTONIO in like manner, attended by ADRIAN and FRANCISCO they all enter the circle which PROSPERO had made, and there stand charmed; which PROSPERO observes.</i></div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>A solemn air and the best comforter<br />
To an unsettled fancy cure thy brains,<br />
Now useless, boil'd within thy skull! There stand,<br />
For you are spell-stopp'd.<br />
Holy Gonzalo, honourable man,<br />
Mine eyes, even sociable to the show of thine,<br />
Fall fellowly drops. The charm dissolves apace,<br />
And as the morning steals upon the night,<br />
Melting the darkness, so their rising senses<br />
Begin to chase the ignorant fumes that mantle<br />
Their clearer reason. O good Gonzalo,<br />
My true preserver, and a loyal sir<br />
To him you follow'st! I will pay thy graces<br />
Home both in word and deed. Most cruelly<br />
Didst thou, Alonso, use me and my daughter:<br />
Thy brother was a furtherer in the act.<br />
Thou art pinch'd fort now, Sebastian. Flesh and blood,<br />
You, brother mine, that entertain'd ambition,<br />
Expell'd remorse and nature; who, with Sebastian,<br />
Whose inward pinches therefore are most strong,<br />
Would here have kill'd your king; I do forgive thee,<br />
Unnatural though thou art. Their understanding<br />
Begins to swell, and the approaching tide<br />
Will shortly fill the reasonable shore<br />
That now lies foul and muddy. Not one of them<br />
That yet looks on me, or would know me Ariel,<br />
Fetch me the hat and rapier in my cell:<br />
I will discase me, and myself present<br />
As I was sometime Milan: quickly, spirit;<br />
Thou shalt ere long be free.
</div></blockquote>

<blockquote><div><i>ARIEL sings and helps to attire him</i></div></blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote><div>Where the bee sucks. there suck I:<br />
In a cowslip's bell I lie;<br />
There I couch when owls do cry.<br />
On the bat's back I do fly<br />
After summer merrily.<br />
Merrily, merrily shall I live now<br />
Under the blossom that hangs on the bough.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Why, that's my dainty Ariel! I shall miss thee:<br />
But yet thou shalt have freedom: so, so, so.<br />
To the king's ship, invisible as thou art:<br />
There shalt thou find the mariners asleep<br />
Under the hatches; the master and the BOATSWAIN<br />
Being awake, enforce them to this place,<br />
And presently, I prithee.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote><div>I drink the air before me, and return<br />
Or ere your pulse twice beat.
</div></blockquote>

<blockquote><div><i>Exit</i></div></blockquote>

<h3>GONZALO</h3>
<blockquote><div>All torment, trouble, wonder and amazement<br />
Inhabits here: some heavenly power guide us<br />
Out of this fearful country!
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Behold, sir king,<br />
The wronged Duke of Milan, Prospero:<br />
For more assurance that a living prince<br />
Does now speak to thee, I embrace thy body;<br />
And to thee and thy company I bid<br />
A hearty welcome.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Whether thou best he or no,<br />
Or some enchanted trifle to abuse me,<br />
As late I have been, I not know: thy pulse<br />
Beats as of flesh and blood; and, since I saw thee,<br />
The affliction of my mind amends, with which,<br />
I fear, a madness held me: this must crave,<br />
An if this be at all, a most strange story.<br />
Thy dukedom I resign and do entreat<br />
Thou pardon me my wrongs. But how should Prospero<br />
Be living and be here?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>First, noble friend,<br />
Let me embrace thine age, whose honour cannot<br />
Be measured or confined.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>GONZALO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Whether this be<br />
Or be not, I'll not swear.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>You do yet taste<br />
Some subtilties o' the isle, that will not let you<br />
Believe things certain. Welcome, my friends all!<br />
But you, my brace of lords, were I so minded,<br />
I here could pluck his highness' frown upon you<br />
And justify you traitors: at this time<br />
I will tell no tales.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>SEBASTIAN</h3>
<blockquote><div>[Aside] The devil speaks in him.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>No.<br />
For you, most wicked sir, whom to call brother<br />
Would even infect my mouth, I do forgive<br />
Thy rankest fault; all of them; and require<br />
My dukedom of thee, which perforce, I know,<br />
Thou must restore.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>If thou be'st Prospero,<br />
Give us particulars of thy preservation;<br />
How thou hast met us here, who three hours since<br />
Were wreck'd upon this shore; where I have lost--<br />
How sharp the point of this remembrance is!--<br />
My dear son Ferdinand.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>I am woe for't, sir.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Irreparable is the loss, and patience<br />
Says it is past her cure.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>I rather think<br />
You have not sought her help, of whose soft grace<br />
For the like loss I have her sovereign aid<br />
And rest myself content.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>You the like loss!
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>As great to me as late; and, supportable<br />
To make the dear loss, have I means much weaker<br />
Than you may call to comfort you, for I<br />
Have lost my daughter.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>A daughter?<br />
O heavens, that they were living both in Naples,<br />
The king and queen there! that they were, I wish<br />
Myself were mudded in that oozy bed<br />
Where my son lies. When did you lose your daughter?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>In this last tempest. I perceive these lords<br />
At this encounter do so much admire<br />
That they devour their reason and scarce think<br />
Their eyes do offices of truth, their words<br />
Are natural breath: but, howsoe'er you have<br />
Been justled from your senses, know for certain<br />
That I am Prospero and that very duke<br />
Which was thrust forth of Milan, who most strangely<br />
Upon this shore, where you were wreck'd, was landed,<br />
To be the lord on't. No more yet of this;<br />
For 'tis a chronicle of day by day,<br />
Not a relation for a breakfast nor<br />
Befitting this first meeting. Welcome, sir;<br />
This cell's my court: here have I few attendants<br />
And subjects none abroad: pray you, look in.<br />
My dukedom since you have given me again,<br />
I will requite you with as good a thing;<br />
At least bring forth a wonder, to content ye<br />
As much as me my dukedom.<br /><br />
<i>Here PROSPERO discovers FERDINAND and MIRANDA playing at chess</i></div></blockquote>

<h3>MIRANDA</h3>
<blockquote><div>Sweet lord, you play me false.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>FERDINAND</h3>
<blockquote><div>No, my dear'st love,<br />
I would not for the world.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>MIRANDA</h3>
<blockquote><div>Yes, for a score of kingdoms you should wrangle,<br />
And I would call it, fair play.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>If this prove<br />
A vision of the Island, one dear son<br />
Shall I twice lose.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>SEBASTIAN</h3>
<blockquote><div>A most high miracle!
</div></blockquote>

<h3>FERDINAND</h3>
<blockquote><div>Though the seas threaten, they are merciful;<br />
I have cursed them without cause.<br />
<i>Kneels</i></div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Now all the blessings<br />
Of a glad father compass thee about!<br />
Arise, and say how thou camest here.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>MIRANDA</h3>
<blockquote><div>O, wonder!<br />
How many goodly creatures are there here!<br />
How beauteous mankind is! O brave new world,<br />
That has such people in't!
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>'Tis new to thee.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>What is this maid with whom thou wast at play?<br />
Your eld'st acquaintance cannot be three hours:<br />
Is she the goddess that hath sever'd us,<br />
And brought us thus together?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>FERDINAND</h3>
<blockquote><div>Sir, she is mortal;<br />
But by immortal Providence she's mine:<br />
I chose her when I could not ask my father<br />
For his advice, nor thought I had one. She<br />
Is daughter to this famous Duke of Milan,<br />
Of whom so often I have heard renown,<br />
But never saw before; of whom I have<br />
Received a second life; and second father<br />
This lady makes him to me.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>I am hers:<br />
But, O, how oddly will it sound that I<br />
Must ask my child forgiveness!
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>There, sir, stop:<br />
Let us not burthen our remembrance with<br />
A heaviness that's gone.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>GONZALO</h3>
<blockquote><div>I have inly wept,<br />
Or should have spoke ere this. Look down, you god,<br />
And on this couple drop a blessed crown!<br />
For it is you that have chalk'd forth the way<br />
Which brought us hither.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>I say, Amen, Gonzalo!
</div></blockquote>

<h3>GONZALO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Was Milan thrust from Milan, that his issue<br />
Should become kings of Naples? O, rejoice<br />
Beyond a common joy, and set it down<br />
With gold on lasting pillars: In one voyage<br />
Did Claribel her husband find at Tunis,<br />
And Ferdinand, her brother, found a wife<br />
Where he himself was lost, Prospero his dukedom<br />
In a poor isle and all of us ourselves<br />
When no man was his own.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>[To FERDINAND and MIRANDA] Give me your hands:<br />
Let grief and sorrow still embrace his heart<br />
That doth not wish you joy!
</div></blockquote>

<h3>GONZALO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Be it so! Amen!<br />

<i>Re-enter ARIEL, with the Master and BOATSWAIN amazedly following</i></div></blockquote>

<h3>GONZALO</h3>
<blockquote><div>O, look, sir, look, sir! here is more of us:<br />
I prophesied, if a gallows were on land,<br />
This fellow could not drown. Now, blasphemy,<br />
That swear'st grace o'erboard, not an oath on shore?<br />
Hast thou no mouth by land? What is the news?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>BOATSWAIN</h3>
<blockquote><div>The best news is, that we have safely found<br />
Our king and company; the next, our ship--<br />
Which, but three glasses since, we gave out split--<br />
Is tight and yare and bravely rigg'd as when<br />
We first put out to sea.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote><div>[Aside to PROSPERO] Sir, all this service<br />
Have I done since I went.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>[Aside to ARIEL] My tricksy spirit!
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>These are not natural events; they strengthen<br />
From strange to stranger. Say, how came you hither?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>BOATSWAIN</h3>
<blockquote><div>If I did think, sir, I were well awake,<br />
I'ld strive to tell you. We were dead of sleep,<br />
And--how we know not--all clapp'd under hatches;<br />
Where but even now with strange and several noises<br />
Of roaring, shrieking, howling, jingling chains,<br />
And more diversity of sounds, all horrible,<br />
We were awaked; straightway, at liberty;<br />
Where we, in all her trim, freshly beheld<br />
Our royal, good and gallant ship, our master<br />
Capering to eye her: on a trice, so please you,<br />
Even in a dream, were we divided from them<br />
And were brought moping hither.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote><div>[Aside to PROSPERO] Was't well done?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>[Aside to ARIEL] Bravely, my diligence. Thou shalt be free.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>This is as strange a maze as e'er men trod<br />
And there is in this business more than nature<br />
Was ever conduct of: some oracle<br />
Must rectify our knowledge.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Sir, my liege,<br />
Do not infest your mind with beating on<br />
The strangeness of this business; at pick'd leisure<br />
Which shall be shortly, single I'll resolve you,<br />
Which to you shall seem probable, of every<br />
These happen'd accidents; till when, be cheerful<br />
And think of each thing well.<br />

<blockquote><div><i>Aside to ARIEL</i></div></blockquote>Come hither, spirit:<br />
Set Caliban and his companions free;<br />
Untie the spell.<br />

<blockquote><div><i>Exit ARIEL</i></div></blockquote>How fares my gracious sir?<br />
There are yet missing of your company<br />
Some few odd lads that you remember not.<br /><br />
<i>Re-enter ARIEL, driving in CALIBAN, STEPHANO and TRINCULO, in their stolen apparel</i></div></blockquote>

<h3>STEPHANO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Every man shift for all the rest, and<br />
let no man take care for himself; for all is<br />
but fortune. Coragio, bully-monster, coragio!
</div></blockquote>

<h3>TRINCULO</h3>
<blockquote><div>If these be true spies which I wear in my head,<br />
here's a goodly sight.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>CALIBAN</h3>
<blockquote><div>O Setebos, these be brave spirits indeed!<br />
How fine my master is! I am afraid<br />
He will chastise me.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>SEBASTIAN</h3>
<blockquote><div>Ha, ha!<br />
What things are these, my lord Antonio?<br />
Will money buy 'em?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ANTONIO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Very like; one of them<br />
Is a plain fish, and, no doubt, marketable.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Mark but the badges of these men, my lords,<br />
Then say if they be true. This mis-shapen knave,<br />
His mother was a witch, and one so strong<br />
That could control the moon, make flows and ebbs,<br />
And deal in her command without her power.<br />
These three have robb'd me; and this demi-devil--<br />
For he's a bastard one--had plotted with them<br />
To take my life. Two of these fellows you<br />
Must know and own; this thing of darkness!<br />
Acknowledge mine.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>CALIBAN</h3>
<blockquote><div>I shall be pinch'd to death.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Is not this Stephano, my drunken butler?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>SEBASTIAN</h3>
<blockquote><div>He is drunk now: where had he wine?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>And Trinculo is reeling ripe: where should they<br />
Find this grand liquor that hath gilded 'em?<br />
How camest thou in this pickle?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>TRINCULO</h3>
<blockquote><div>I have been in such a pickle since I<br />
saw you last that, I fear me, will never out of<br />
my bones: I shall not fear fly-blowing.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>SEBASTIAN</h3>
<blockquote><div>Why, how now, Stephano!
</div></blockquote>

<h3>STEPHANO</h3>
<blockquote><div>O, touch me not; I am not Stephano, but a cramp.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>You'ld be king o' the isle, sirrah?
</div></blockquote>

<h3>STEPHANO</h3>
<blockquote><div>I should have been a sore one then.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>This is a strange thing as e'er I look'd on.<br /><br />
<i>Pointing to Caliban</i></div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>He is as disproportion'd in his manners<br />
As in his shape. Go, sirrah, to my cell;<br />
Take with you your companions; as you look<br />
To have my pardon, trim it handsomely.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>CALIBAN</h3>
<blockquote><div>Ay, that I will; and I'll be wise hereafter<br />
And seek for grace. What a thrice-double ass<br />
Was I, to take this drunkard for a god<br />
And worship this dull fool!
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Go to; away!
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Hence, and bestow your luggage where you found it.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>SEBASTIAN</h3>
<blockquote><div>Or stole it, rather.
</div></blockquote>

<blockquote><div><i>Exeunt CALIBAN, STEPHANO, and TRINCULO</i></div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>Sir, I invite your highness and your train<br />
To my poor cell, where you shall take your rest<br />
For this one night; which, part of it, I'll waste<br />
With such discourse as, I not doubt, shall make it<br />
Go quick away; the story of my life<br />
And the particular accidents gone by<br />
Since I came to this isle: and in the morn<br />
I'll bring you to your ship and so to Naples,<br />
Where I have hope to see the nuptial<br />
Of these our dear-beloved solemnized;<br />
And thence retire me to my Milan, where<br />
Every third thought shall be my grave.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>ALONSO</h3>
<blockquote><div>I long<br />
To hear the story of your life, which must<br />
Take the ear strangely.
</div></blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><div>I'll deliver all;<br />
And promise you calm seas, auspicious gales<br />
And sail so expeditious that shall catch<br />
Your royal fleet far off.<br />

<blockquote><div><i>Aside to ARIEL</i></div></blockquote>My Ariel, chick,<br />
That is thy charge: then to the elements<br />
Be free, and fare thou well! Please you, draw near.<br />

<blockquote><div><i>Exeunt</i></div></blockquote>EPILOGUE<br />
SPOKEN BY PROSPERO<br />
Now my charms are all o'erthrown,<br />
And what strength I have's mine own,<br />
Which is most faint: now, 'tis true,<br />
I must be here confined by you,<br />
Or sent to Naples. Let me not,<br />
Since I have my dukedom got<br />
And pardon'd the deceiver, dwell<br />
In this bare island by your spell;<br />
But release me from my bands<br />
With the help of your good hands:<br />
Gentle breath of yours my sails<br />
Must fill, or else my project fails,<br />
Which was to please. Now I want<br />
Spirits to enforce, art to enchant,<br />
And my ending is despair,<br />
Unless I be relieved by prayer,<br />
Which pierces so that it assaults<br />
Mercy itself and frees all faults.<br />
As you from crimes would pardon'd be,<br />
Let your indulgence set me free.
</div></blockquote>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = createList;

function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
   if (object.attachEvent)
       object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
   else if (object.addEventListener)
       object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}


function uniqueElemText(elemName) {
   elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elemName);
   elemsArray = new Array();

   for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) elemsArray[i]=elems[i].innerHTML;  
   elemsArray.sort();
   for (i=0; i<elemsArray.length-1; i++) {
      if (elemsArray[i]==elemsArray[i+1]) {
         elemsArray.splice(i+1,1);
         i--;
      }
   }
   return elemsArray;
}

function createList(){
    var option;
    var characters = new Array();
    var select = document.createElement('select');
        select.setAttribute('id', 'charList');
        select.addEventListener('change', filter, false);
    var charBox = document.getElementById('characterList');
        charBox.innerHTML = '<p>Show Only Line By:</p>';
        charBox.appendChild(select);

    var tempChar = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');
    for(var i = 0; i < tempChar.length; i++)
        if(characters.indexOf(tempChar[i].innerHTML) == -1)
            characters.push(tempChar[i].innerHTML);
    delete tempChar;
    characters.sort();

    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Show All Character Lines";
    option.value = 'ALL';
    select.add(option);

    for(var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++)
    {
        option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = characters[i];
        option.value = characters[i];
        select.add(option);
    }
}

function filter(){
    var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
    var elemList = scene.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var list = document.getElementById('charList');
    var character = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;

    var hide = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < elemList.length; i++) {
        var elem = elemList[i];
        if (elem.tagName == "H3") {
            hide = (elemList[i].innerHTML.indexOf(character) == -1)
        }

        if (hide) {
            elem.style.opacity = 0.0;
        } else {
            elem.style.opacity = 1.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I had to remove some blockquotes with titles due to limitation  of characters in answer

Snippet below

```js
window.onload = createList;

function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
  if (object.attachEvent)
    object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
  else if (object.addEventListener)
    object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}


function uniqueElemText(elemName) {
  elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elemName);
  elemsArray = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) elemsArray[i] = elems[i].innerHTML;
  elemsArray.sort();
  for (i = 0; i < elemsArray.length - 1; i++) {
    if (elemsArray[i] == elemsArray[i + 1]) {
      elemsArray.splice(i + 1, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return elemsArray;
}

function createList() {
  var option;
  var characters = new Array();
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  select.setAttribute('id', 'charList');
  select.addEventListener('change', filter, false);
  var charBox = document.getElementById('characterList');
  charBox.innerHTML = '<p>Show Only Line By:</p>';
  charBox.appendChild(select);

  var tempChar = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');
  for (var i = 0; i < tempChar.length; i++)
    if (characters.indexOf(tempChar[i].innerHTML) == -1)
      characters.push(tempChar[i].innerHTML);
  delete tempChar;
  characters.sort();

  option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = "Show All Character Lines";
  option.value = 'ALL';
  select.add(option);

  for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = characters[i];
    option.value = characters[i];
    select.add(option);
  }
}

function filter() {
  var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
  var elemList = scene.getElementsByTagName('h3');
  var list = document.getElementById('charList');
  var character = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value.trim();

  if (character == "ALL") {
    for (var i = 0; i < elemList.length; i++) {
      console.log()
      var elem = elemList[i];
      elem.style.display = "block";
      elem.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('style', "display:block;");
    }
    return
  }

  var hide = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < elemList.length; i++) {
    var elem = elemList[i];

    if (elem.tagName == "H3") {
      hide = (elemList[i].textContent.trim().indexOf(character) == -1)
    }

    if (hide == true) {
      elem.style.display = "none";
      elem.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('style', "display:none;");
      console.log(elem.nextElementSibling.style.display)
    } else {
      elem.style.display = "block";
      elem.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('style', "display:block;");
      console.log(elem.nextElementSibling.tagName)
    }
  }
}
```

```css
blockquote,
h3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>

  <title>The Tempest, Act V, Scene 1</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link href="plays.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="scene.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="linklist">
    <img src="plays_out.jpg" alt="The Plays" />
    <img src="son_out.jpg" alt="The Sonnets" />
    <img src="bio_out.jpg" alt="Biography" />
    <img src="globe_out.jpg" alt="The Globe" />
    <img src="strat_out.jpg" alt="Stratford" />
  </div>
  <div id="title">
    <img src="tempest.jpg" alt="The Tempest" />
  </div>
  <div id="actList">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>ACT I</td>
        <td>ACT II</td>
        <td>ACT III</td>
        <td>ACT IV</td>
        <td>ACT V</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="characterList"></div>


  <div id="sceneIntro">
    <h2>Lines from Act V, Scene 1</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="scene">
    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div><i>Enter PROSPERO in his magic robes, and ARIEL</i>
      </div>
    </blockquote>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Now does my project gather to a head:
        <br />My charms crack not; my spirits obey; and time
        <br />Goes upright with his carriage. How's the day?
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ARIEL</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>On the sixth hour; at which time, my lord,
        <br />You said our work should cease.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>I did say so,
        <br />When first I raised the tempest. Say, my spirit,
        <br/>How fares the king and's followers?
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ARIEL</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Confined together
        <br />In the same fashion as you gave in charge,
        <br />Just as you left them; all prisoners, sir,
        <br />In the line-grove which weather-fends your cell;
        <br />They cannot budge till your release. The king,
        <br />His brother and yours, abide all three distracted

      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>

      <div>Dost thou think so, spirit?
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ARIEL</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Mine would, sir, were I human.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>And mine shall.
        <br />Hast thou, which art but air, a touch, a feeling
        <br />Of their afflictions, and shall not myself,
        <br />One of their kind, that relish all as sharply,
        <br />Passion as they, be kindlier moved than thou art?
        <br />Though with their high wrongs I am struck to the quick,
        <br />Yet with my nobler reason 'gaitist my fury
        <br />Do I take part: the rarer action is
        <br />In virtue than in vengeance: they being penitent,
        <br />The sole drift of my purpose doth extend
        <br />Not a frown further. Go release them, Ariel:
        <br />My charms I'll break, their senses I'll restore,
        <br />And they shall be themselves.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ARIEL</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>I'll fetch them, sir.</div>
    </blockquote>

    <blockquote>
      <div><i>Exit</i>
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote style="">
      <div>Ye elves of hills, brooks, standing lakes and groves,
        <br />And ye that on the sands with printless foot
        <br />Do chase the ebbing Neptune and do fly him
        <br />When he comes back; you demi-puppets that
        <br />By moonshine do the green sour ringlets make,
        <br />Whereof the ewe not bites, and you whose pastime
        <br />Is to make midnight mushrooms, that rejoice
        <br />To hear the solemn curfew; by whose aid,
        <br />Weak masters though ye be, I have bedimm'd
        <br />The noontide sun, call'd forth the mutinous winds,
        <br />And 'twixt the green sea and the azured vault
        <br />Set roaring war: to the dread rattling thunder
        <br />Have I given fire and rifted Jove's stout oak
        <br />With his own bolt; the strong-based promontory
        <br />Have I made shake and by the spurs pluck'd up
        <br />The pine and cedar: graves at my command
        <br />Have waked their sleepers, oped, and let 'em forth
        <br />By my so potent art. But this rough magic
        <br />I here abjure, and, when I have required
        <br />Some heavenly music, which even now I do,
        <br />To work mine end upon their senses that
        <br />This airy charm is for, I'll break my staff,
        <br />Bury it certain fathoms in the earth,
        <br />And deeper than did ever plummet sound
        <br />I'll drown my book.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <blockquote>
      <div><i>Solemn music</i>
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <blockquote>
      <div><i>Re-enter ARIEL before: then ALONSO, with a frantic gesture, attended by GONZALO; SEBASTIAN and ANTONIO in like manner, attended by ADRIAN and FRANCISCO they all enter the circle which PROSPERO had made, and there stand charmed; which PROSPERO observes.</i>
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>A solemn air and the best comforter
        <br />To an unsettled fancy cure thy brains,
        <br />Now useless, boil'd within thy skull! There stand,
        <br />For you are spell-stopp'd.
        <br />Holy Gonzalo, honourable man,
        <br />Mine eyes, even sociable to the show of thine,
        <br />Fall fellowly drops. The charm dissolves apace,
        <br />And as the morning steals upon the night,
        <br />Melting the darkness, so their rising senses
        <br />Begin to chase the ignorant fumes that mantle
        <br />Their clearer reason. O good Gonzalo,
        <br />My true preserver, and a loyal sir
        <br />To him you follow'st! I will pay thy graces
        <br />Home both in word and deed. Most cruelly
        <br />Didst thou, Alonso, use me and my daughter:
        <br />Thy brother was a furtherer in the act.
        <br />Thou art pinch'd fort now, Sebastian. Flesh and blood,
        <br />You, brother mine, that entertain'd ambition,
        <br />Expell'd remorse and nature; who, with Sebastian,
        <br />Whose inward pinches therefore are most strong,
        <br />Would here have kill'd your king; I do forgive thee,
        <br />Unnatural though thou art. Their understanding
        <br />Begins to swell, and the approaching tide
        <br />Will shortly fill the reasonable shore
        <br />That now lies foul and muddy. Not one of them
        <br />That yet looks on me, or would know me Ariel,
        <br />Fetch me the hat and rapier in my cell:
        <br />I will discase me, and myself present
        <br />As I was sometime Milan: quickly, spirit;
        <br />Thou shalt ere long be free.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <blockquote>
      <div><i>ARIEL sings and helps to attire him</i>
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ARIEL</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Where the bee sucks. there suck I:
        <br />In a cowslip's bell I lie;
        <br />There I couch when owls do cry.
        <br />On the bat's back I do fly
        <br />After summer merrily.
        <br />Merrily, merrily shall I live now
        <br />Under the blossom that hangs on the bough.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Why, that's my dainty Ariel! I shall miss thee:
        <br />But yet thou shalt have freedom: so, so, so.
        <br />To the king's ship, invisible as thou art:
        <br />There shalt thou find the mariners asleep
        <br />Under the hatches; the master and the BOATSWAIN
        <br />Being awake, enforce them to this place,
        <br />And presently, I prithee.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ARIEL</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>I drink the air before me, and return
        <br />Or ere your pulse twice beat.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <blockquote>
      <div><i>Exit</i>
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>GONZALO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>All torment, trouble, wonder and amazement
        <br />Inhabits here: some heavenly power guide us
        <br />Out of this fearful country!
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Behold, sir king,
        <br />The wronged Duke of Milan, Prospero:
        <br />For more assurance that a living prince
        <br />Does now speak to thee, I embrace thy body;
        <br />And to thee and thy company I bid
        <br />A hearty welcome.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ALONSO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Whether thou best he or no,
        <br />Or some enchanted trifle to abuse me,
        <br />As late I have been, I not know: thy pulse
        <br />Beats as of flesh and blood; and, since I saw thee,
        <br />The affliction of my mind amends, with which,
        <br />I fear, a madness held me: this must crave,
        <br />An if this be at all, a most strange story.
        <br />Thy dukedom I resign and do entreat
        <br />Thou pardon me my wrongs. But how should Prospero
        <br />Be living and be here?
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>First, noble friend,
        <br />Let me embrace thine age, whose honour cannot
        <br />Be measured or confined.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>GONZALO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Whether this be
        <br />Or be not, I'll not swear.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>You do yet taste
        <br />Some subtilties o' the isle, that will not let you
        <br />Believe things certain. Welcome, my friends all!
        <br />But you, my brace of lords, were I so minded,
        <br />I here could pluck his highness' frown upon you
        <br />And justify you traitors: at this time
        <br />I will tell no tales.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>SEBASTIAN</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>[Aside] The devil speaks in him.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>No.
        <br />For you, most wicked sir, whom to call brother
        <br />Would even infect my mouth, I do forgive
        <br />Thy rankest fault; all of them; and require
        <br />My dukedom of thee, which perforce, I know,
        <br />Thou must restore.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ALONSO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>If thou be'st Prospero,
        <br />Give us particulars of thy preservation;
        <br />How thou hast met us here, who three hours since
        <br />Were wreck'd upon this shore; where I have lost--
        <br />How sharp the point of this remembrance is!--
        <br />My dear son Ferdinand.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>I am woe for't, sir.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ALONSO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Irreparable is the loss, and patience
        <br />Says it is past her cure.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>I rather think
        <br />You have not sought her help, of whose soft grace
        <br />For the like loss I have her sovereign aid
        <br />And rest myself content.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ALONSO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>You the like loss!
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>As great to me as late; and, supportable
        <br />To make the dear loss, have I means much weaker
        <br />Than you may call to comfort you, for I
        <br />Have lost my daughter.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ALONSO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>A daughter?
        <br />O heavens, that they were living both in Naples,
        <br />The king and queen there! that they were, I wish
        <br />Myself were mudded in that oozy bed
        <br />Where my son lies. When did you lose your daughter?
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>In this last tempest. I perceive these lords
        <br />At this encounter do so much admire
        <br />That they devour their reason and scarce think
        <br />Their eyes do offices of truth, their words
        <br />Are natural breath: but, howsoe'er you have
        <br />Been justled from your senses, know for certain
        <br />That I am Prospero and that very duke
        <br />Which was thrust forth of Milan, who most strangely
        <br />Upon this shore, where you were wreck'd, was landed,
        <br />To be the lord on't. No more yet of this;
        <br />For 'tis a chronicle of day by day,
        <br />Not a relation for a breakfast nor
        <br />Befitting this first meeting. Welcome, sir;
        <br />This cell's my court: here have I few attendants
        <br />And subjects none abroad: pray you, look in.
        <br />My dukedom since you have given me again,
        <br />I will requite you with as good a thing;
        <br />At least bring forth a wonder, to content ye
        <br />As much as me my dukedom.
        <br />
        <br />
        <i>Here PROSPERO discovers FERDINAND and MIRANDA playing at chess</i>
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>MIRANDA</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Sweet lord, you play me false.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>FERDINAND</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>No, my dear'st love,
        <br />I would not for the world.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>MIRANDA</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Yes, for a score of kingdoms you should wrangle,
        <br />And I would call it, fair play.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ALONSO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>If this prove
        <br />A vision of the Island, one dear son
        <br />Shall I twice lose.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>SEBASTIAN</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>A most high miracle!
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>FERDINAND</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Though the seas threaten, they are merciful;
        <br />I have cursed them without cause.
        <br />
        <i>Kneels</i>
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ALONSO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Now all the blessings
        <br />Of a glad father compass thee about!
        <br />Arise, and say how thou camest here.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>MIRANDA</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>O, wonder!
        <br />How many goodly creatures are there here!
        <br />How beauteous mankind is! O brave new world,
        <br />That has such people in't!
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>'Tis new to thee.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ALONSO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>What is this maid with whom thou wast at play?
        <br />Your eld'st acquaintance cannot be three hours:
        <br />Is she the goddess that hath sever'd us,
        <br />And brought us thus together?
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>FERDINAND</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Sir, she is mortal;
        <br />But by immortal Providence she's mine:
        <br />I chose her when I could not ask my father
        <br />For his advice, nor thought I had one. She
        <br />Is daughter to this famous Duke of Milan,
        <br />Of whom so often I have heard renown,
        <br />But never saw before; of whom I have
        <br />Received a second life; and second father
        <br />This lady makes him to me.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ALONSO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>I am hers:
        <br />But, O, how oddly will it sound that I
        <br />Must ask my child forgiveness!
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>There, sir, stop:
        <br />Let us not burthen our remembrance with
        <br />A heaviness that's gone.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>GONZALO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>I have inly wept,
        <br />Or should have spoke ere this. Look down, you god,
        <br />And on this couple drop a blessed crown!
        <br />For it is you that have chalk'd forth the way
        <br />Which brought us hither.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ALONSO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>I say, Amen, Gonzalo!
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>GONZALO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Was Milan thrust from Milan, that his issue
        <br />Should become kings of Naples? O, rejoice
        <br />Beyond a common joy, and set it down
        <br />With gold on lasting pillars: In one voyage
        <br />Did Claribel her husband find at Tunis,
        <br />And Ferdinand, her brother, found a wife
        <br />Where he himself was lost, Prospero his dukedom
        <br />In a poor isle and all of us ourselves
        <br />When no man was his own.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ALONSO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>[To FERDINAND and MIRANDA] Give me your hands:
        <br />Let grief and sorrow still embrace his heart
        <br />That doth not wish you joy!
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>GONZALO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Be it so! Amen!
        <br />

        <i>Re-enter ARIEL, with the Master and BOATSWAIN amazedly following</i>
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>GONZALO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>O, look, sir, look, sir! here is more of us:
        <br />I prophesied, if a gallows were on land,
        <br />This fellow could not drown. Now, blasphemy,
        <br />That swear'st grace o'erboard, not an oath on shore?
        <br />Hast thou no mouth by land? What is the news?
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>BOATSWAIN</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>The best news is, that we have safely found
        <br />Our king and company; the next, our ship--
        <br />Which, but three glasses since, we gave out split--
        <br />Is tight and yare and bravely rigg'd as when
        <br />We first put out to sea.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ARIEL</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>[Aside to PROSPERO] Sir, all this service
        <br />Have I done since I went.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>[Aside to ARIEL] My tricksy spirit!
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ALONSO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>These are not natural events; they strengthen
        <br />From strange to stranger. Say, how came you hither?
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>BOATSWAIN</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>If I did think, sir, I were well awake,
        <br />I'ld strive to tell you. We were dead of sleep,
        <br />And--how we know not--all clapp'd under hatches;
        <br />Where but even now with strange and several noises
        <br />Of roaring, shrieking, howling, jingling chains,
        <br />And more diversity of sounds, all horrible,
        <br />We were awaked; straightway, at liberty;
        <br />Where we, in all her trim, freshly beheld
        <br />Our royal, good and gallant ship, our master
        <br />Capering to eye her: on a trice, so please you,
        <br />Even in a dream, were we divided from them
        <br />And were brought moping hither.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ARIEL</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>[Aside to PROSPERO] Was't well done?
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>[Aside to ARIEL] Bravely, my diligence. Thou shalt be free.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>ALONSO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>This is as strange a maze as e'er men trod
        <br />And there is in this business more than nature
        <br />Was ever conduct of: some oracle
        <br />Must rectify our knowledge.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>PROSPERO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Sir, my liege,
        <br />Do not infest your mind with beating on
        <br />The strangeness of this business; at pick'd leisure
        <br />Which shall be shortly, single I'll resolve you,
        <br />Which to you shall seem probable, of every
        <br />These happen'd accidents; till when, be cheerful
        <br />And think of each thing well.
        <br />

        <blockquote>
          <div><i>Aside to ARIEL</i>
          </div>
        </blockquote>Come hither, spirit:
        <br />Set Caliban and his companions free;
        <br />Untie the spell.
        <br />

        <blockquote>
          <div><i>Exit ARIEL</i>
          </div>
        </blockquote>How fares my gracious sir?
        <br />There are yet missing of your company
        <br />Some few odd lads that you remember not.
        <br />
        <br />
        <i>Re-enter ARIEL, driving in CALIBAN, STEPHANO and TRINCULO, in their stolen apparel</i>
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>STEPHANO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Every man shift for all the rest, and
        <br />let no man take care for himself; for all is
        <br />but fortune. Coragio, bully-monster, coragio!
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>TRINCULO</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>If these be true spies which I wear in my head,
        <br />here's a goodly sight.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>CALIBAN</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>O Setebos, these be brave spirits indeed!
        <br />How fine my master is! I am afraid
        <br />He will chastise me.
      </div>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>SEBASTIAN</h3>
    <blockquote>
      <div>Ha, ha!
        <br />What things are these, my lord Antonio?
        <br />Will money buy 'em?
      </div>
    </blockquote>
```

Comment: I actually did some modification to your existing codes.in terms of styling..also note that I applied a css section  for styling blockquote and header tags to :display:none" when window loads.

Comment: I had already figured out how to display the character's dialogue correctly. My main issue now is... When you filter the dialogue for a certain character, then try filtering back to "Show All Character Lines", it is blank instead of showing all character lines. I tried your code and it had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had figured out I could just replace `elem.style.opacity = 0.0;` with `elem.style.display = 'none';`.

I am still leaving the question open in case someone can help me figure out how to to reset the list and show all the lines of dialogue when selecting the default option of "Show All Character Lines".